# Xamarin.Forms: Units for Constraints in a RelativeLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Does anyone know what type of unit the "value" for Constraints.Constant(double value) should be?

I'm trying to create my Xamarin.Forms pages with RelativeLayouts, but when I tried using pixels for the value, the elements are **much** larger than they should be.

Additionally, I use Contraints.RelativeToParent(), but some elements (specifically Images) appear skewed as if the "parent" does not take up the full size of the screen. Do RelativeLayout's have predetermined bounds?

(I'm using calculations such as return parent.Width *0.3906 which should return 293, but instead returns 124.992) This is based off of the iPhone 6 Simulator.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no platform agnostic way of doing the calculations you are trying to achieve. You would need to build a native implementation to call out to the particular platform for a size you can use.

You will need to follow the DependencyService pattern:

```
public interface IDeviceSize
{
    double DeviceHeight { get; }

    double DeviceWidth { get; }
}


public class DeviceSize_Android : IDeviceSize
{
    Context _context;

    public DeviceSize()
    {
        _context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
    }

    #region IDeviceSize implementation

    public double DeviceHeight
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToDouble(_context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / _context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity);
        }
    }

    public double DeviceWidth
    {
        get
        {

            return Convert.ToDouble(_context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / _context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public class DeviceSize_iOS : IDeviceSize
{
    public DeviceSize()
    {
    }

    #region IDeviceSize implementation

    public double DeviceHeight
    {
        get
        {
            CGRect screenRect = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
            return screenRect.Height;
        }
    }

    public double DeviceWidth
    {
        get
        {
            CGRect screenRect = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
            return screenRect.Width;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

You need to post some of your code in order to assess your requirements further as there may be no need to include specific sizes in the way that you are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That seems to make sense. Here's the code I use to position the image that displays oddly.

`layout.Children.Add(timeImage,
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => { return parent.Width * 0.52 ; }), 
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => { return parent.Height * 0.56 - (parent.Height * 0.0727) / 2.0; }),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => { return parent.Width * 0.3906; }),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => { return parent.Height * 0.0727; }));`

Comment: Why are you trying to lay the elements out so specifically? If you upload a screenshot of what you are trying to create I can see if there is an easier way.

Comment: Apparently I need a higher rating (10) before I can post any images. Let me see what I can do about that.